# Choose return class type based on parameter with Java 7

Tags: java, java-7

I am looking for whether is possible or not to make this in Java 7:

Now, I have this functions like this in several services, which third parameter will be diffent in each one:

```
final RequestDTO1 requestDTO = (RequestDTO1) getDTO(param, RequestDTO1.class);

final RequestDTO2 requestDTO = (RequestDTO2) getDTO(param, RequestDTO2.class);

final RequestDTO3 requestDTO = (RequestDTO3) getDTO(param, RequestDTO3.class);
```

This is the getDTO signature:

```
protected Object getMessage(Object param, Class clazz);
```

There is some way of indicating the getDTO function that I want to return an object of the class indicated by the third parameter without using the casting?

```
final RequestDTO1 requestDTO = getDTO(param, RequestDTO1.class);

final RequestDTO2 requestDTO = getDTO(param, RequestDTO2.class);

final RequestDTO3 requestDTO = getDTO(param, RequestDTO3.class);
```

Comment: Can you modify the `getDTO()` method (especially its signature)?

Comment: what's the problem with casting?

Comment: @BhavikShah type-safety

Comment: @Puce : we have generics for that right?

Comment: @BhavikShah yes, that's one way to solve it. See the provided solutions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify the method is generified (note this is independent from the class generification - it is done at a *method* level), and return the generic type like this:

```
protected <T> T getMessage(Object param, Class<T> clazz);
```

See the [Generic methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) section in the Java Tutorial for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
protected <T> T getMessage(Object param, Class<T> clazz);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
protected <T> T getMessage(Object param, Class<T> clazz);
```